# jUnit assertEquals string return "50" expected "50" but returned nothing test

Tags: java, junit

Experimenting with jUnit and REST webservices. 
Wrote the following class and test class and made a test. Either I've written the test incorrectly or the service is incorrectly written.

I believe it should `return "50";`
OR 
   is it supposed to return the Path and also 50? How do I write that test then?

The class:

```
@Path("/QAService")
public class QAService {
    @GET()
    //@Path("/")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getServiceInfo() {
        return "50";
    }
```

The test of the class:

```
public class QAServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void testgetServiceInfo() {

        String expected = "50";   

        //create static variable to call non-static variable. assertEquals.
        QAService qas = new QAService();
        qas.getServiceInfo();
        assertEquals(expected, qas);
    }
```

But got Test Results:

```
expected:<50> but was:<com.hey.BLA.zurich.QAService@52bb855b>
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at com.hey.BLA.zurich.QAServiceTest.testgetServiceInfo(QAServiceTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Comment: The method `getServiceInfo()` returns `"50"`.

Comment: It is not supposed to return the path. The path is the path you go to in your browser, that will result in `getServiceInfo()` being executed. So, if you go to `/QAService` (e.g. in a browser) you will see the text `50`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
assertEquals(expected, qas.getServiceInfo());
```